# Display all columns in a grid in php MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I know to display the values from a table in MySql in a PHP page. This is what I do:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
{
//print the values using echo
}
```

The problem is I have 35 columns in the table I use and I have 4 such tables. Is there a simpler way than just echo-ing each column. Also I have to print the table headers. Tried a few links in google, didn't get a satisfactory answer. Direct answer or link will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just loop over the columns. If you get a associative instead of a numerical array you can print the keys when you get the first row.

Comment: You got a link or anything ? You mean have associative for the header and numerical for the columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the column names of a table from a query, you can do something like this:

```
$c=0;
$myarray = array();
while ($c < mysql_num_fields($result))
{
     # Get field name
     $fld = mysql_fetch_field($result, $c);

     # Put field name in array
     $myarray[] = $fld->name;

     # Count + 1 for next field
     $c++;
}

echo "<table style='border:1px solid #ccc;'>\n";
echo "<thead>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
foreach($myarray as $columnheading) {
    echo "<th>".$columnheading."</th>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</thead>\n";
echo "<tbody>\n";
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach($row as $td) {
            echo "<td>".$td."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}
echo "</tbody>\n";
echo "</table>";
```

You have the column names in a array. Add print_r($myarray) to see what columns are generated.

**EDIT: added full example.**

Comment: $myarray can be printed in a table header ? And regarding the other part of the question ? Anyway I can reduce the number of times I print the columns ?

Comment: Hi man, i added a full example, hope it helps. Table is really sloppy but it does what you need. You need to tweak it a little.

Comment: Good! Let me know, don't forget to accept if it's ok!

Comment: Note that mysql will be deprecated soon (PHP 5.5), just like @Ollie Jones said, you should use mysqli classes.

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php)

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM sometable");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joey has written an excellent answer, just wanted to add that, mysql_num_fields() function has been deprecated since PHP 7.0 and

```
mysqli_num_fields();
```

should be used in it's stead. [Deprecation note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php)

Answer (score -1):

The trick you need is to retrieve the result set's metadata. I refuse to help you do anything with the deprecated and dangerous `mysql_` interface, so my answer relates to `mysqli_`.

Here's documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Here's some possible code you could use:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" .
        $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");

if (!$res) {
    die "Query failed: (" . $res->errno . ") " . $res->error;
}

$rownumber = 0;
echo "<table>\n";
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
  if (0 == $rownumber) {
    /* first result set row? look at the keys=column nanes */
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach (array_keys($row) as $colname) {
      echo "<td>$colname</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  $rownumber ++;

  echo "<tr>";
  foreach (array_values($row) as $colval) {
    echo "<td>$colval</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
$res->close();
```

As far as reducing the number of times you call "echo", there's no particularly good reason to do that. But if you must you can do something like this to accumulate an output string.

```
  $out = "";
  $out .= "<tr>";
  foreach (array_values($row) as $colval) {
    $out .= "<td>$colval</td>";
  }
  $out .= "</tr>\n";
  echo $out;
  $out = "";
```